# Geometry notation: what does $m\angle ABC$ mean?

Tags: geometry, notation

I see in some math formulation that a certain angle is called, let's say

$$\angle ABC$$

but there is a letter put in front of the angle notation.

$$m\angle ABC$$

What does the $m$ represent here? A factor?

Comment: Try to use LaTeX to write accurately mathematics here. You also didn't write what the angle is called, "let say..."

Comment: <ABC and m<ABC.. I dont know why it doesnt show up in the question..

Comment: Do you mean $\theta(x)$?

Comment: You're going to give more context, for example to write down a complete exercise. The letter $\;m\;$ is many times reserved for *slope* in analytic geometry.

Comment: It's because the `<` hides the subsequent text when the post is rendered. I have fixed it.

Comment: $m∠ABC$ means the measure of $∠ABC$, and is also written as $∡ABC$.

Answer (score 4):

$\angle ABC$ : The angle ABC

$m\angle ABC$: The measure of $\angle ABC$

So, when $\angle ABC \cong \angle DFG$ , that means,  $m\angle ABC = m\angle DFG$

Comment: If m∠ABC=m∠DFG does that also imply m∠ABC≅m∠DFG ?

Answer (score 3):

The notation $m\angle ABC$ typically denotes "the measure of angle $ABC$."

Comment: To clarify, the $m$ is sometimes used to distinguish between the measure of the angle ($m\angle ABC$ = a number, in degrees/radians) and the actual angle itself (the geometric object $\angle ABC$).

Comment: Thanks for all your replies and Cameron has understood the badly formulated question correct. 

But if the angle is, lets say <ABC = 50 degrees. What is the need of m<ABC then? Doesnt <ABC already denote the measure of the angle?

Comment: @Hilbert No, $\angle ABC$ is used to denote the angle itself, as a geometric object. Of course, this is a minor distinction, and some authors may choose to be lax in the notation.

Comment: @Hilbert: As blf points out, $\angle ABC$ denotes the angle, itself, while $m\angle ABC$ is its measure. For example, suppose we have an equilateral triangle with vertices $A,B,C.$ Then $\angle ABC$ occurs at the intersection of the segments $AB$ and $BC$, while $m\angle ABC$ is the measure of that angle. The distinction isn't always important, but sometimes it is.

Comment: Thanks Cameron & blf.. Perfectly explained. 

I have been searching for geometry textbooks that explains things like this and deals with elementary things like Congruence, Arc, Geometric shapes like triangles and so on.
Any recommendations?

Comment: @Hilbert: I'm afraid not. That might be better suited as a new question with the `(reference-request)` tag, and perhaps a link to this question for more context.

Comment: @CameronBuie As you mentioned above, just curious to know where is the distinction between ∠ABC and  m∠ABC important?

Answer (score 2):

∠ABC refers to the physical angle itself while m∠ABC refers to its measure. There isn't any difference between these two and it is absolutely correct to use any of them...Some people just want to formalize things; these people think-"I have a car that is priced at 50000dollars, so i am driving a car and not 50000dollars" and so want to differentiate between little everything.